# Extra stars created, most efficient way to get rid of them?

Tags: python-2.7, astronomy

I have created a program to locate stars from a  BW picture, but unfortunately on long exposure times the star becomes smeared causing the program to create a duplicate star next to the star (see image). What is the best way to remove the unwanted star?

[image: img]

This is the current code i am using:

```
def starfinder(filename) :

f=pyfits.open(filename)
image_data=snd.median_filter(f[0].data,3)                              #gets rid of the hot pixels
thld = image_data.mean() + 2*image_data.std()                          #limits the pixel value of bright stars
labels, number = snd.label(image_data > thld, np.ones((3,3)))          #turns any values over the threshold into a 3x3 array of ones
centres = snd.center_of_mass(image_data, labels, range(1,number+1))    #center of mass finds the centre of the 3x3 array

star_centres = np.around(centres, decimals=0)
y = np.array(star_centres)[:,0]
x = np.array(star_centres)[:,1]
np.savetxt("star_positions.txt",star_centres)

#plt.plot(x,y,"ro")
plt.scatter(x, y, marker='o', c='r', s=5, label='the data')

return len(x)[enter image description here][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. **Define smear offset**

   Either manualy, or measure it from histogram of star distances. The most ocurent offset is the smear.
2. **for each star**

   check if there is not a smeared star nearby smear offset If yes merge the two into single one. How that depends on the data properties. For example you can use average star position, star position that is in start of thesmear or end, etc ..

Here small **C++** example of how to do this:

```cpp
picture pic1; // your image
const DWORD cl_star =0x008C0000;
const DWORD cl_space=0x00FFFFFF;
const int smear_max=30; // max smear size [pixels]
int i,j,x,y,r=3,dx0,dx1,dy0,dy1;
DWORD c;

List<int> xy;           // star (x,y)
int hisx[smear_max];    // histogram of star dx distances
int hisy[smear_max];    // histogram of star dy distances

// get star coordinates
for (y=0;y<pic1.ys-1;y++)
 for (x=0;x<pic1.xs-1;x++)
  if (pic1.p[y][x].dd==cl_star)
    {
    xy.add(x);
    xy.add(y);
    x++; if (pic1.p[y][x].dd==cl_star) pic1.p[y][x].dd=cl_space;
    y++; if (pic1.p[y][x].dd==cl_star) pic1.p[y][x].dd=cl_space;
    x--; if (pic1.p[y][x].dd==cl_star) pic1.p[y][x].dd=cl_space;
    y--;                               pic1.p[y][x].dd=cl_space;
    }
// compute hisogram of star |dx|,|dy| distance
for (i=0;i<smear_max;i++) hisx[i]=0;
for (i=0;i<smear_max;i++) hisy[i]=0;
for (i=0;i<xy.num;i+=2)
 for (j=i+2;j<xy.num;j+=2)
    {
    x=xy[i+0]-xy[j+0]; if (x<0) x=-x; if (x<smear_max) hisx[x]++;
    y=xy[i+1]-xy[j+1]; if (y<0) y=-y; if (y<smear_max) hisy[y]++;
    }
// find most common ones
for (i=0,j=0;i<smear_max;i++) if (hisx[j]<hisx[i]) j=i; dx0=j-1; dx1=j+1;
for (i=0,j=0;i<smear_max;i++) if (hisy[j]<hisy[i]) j=i; dy0=j-1; dy1=j+1;
// render found stars
pic1.bmp->Canvas->Pen->Color=clBlack;
pic1.bmp->Canvas->Brush->Color=clRed;
for (i=0;i<xy.num;)
    {
    x=xy[i]; i++;
    y=xy[i]; i++;
    pic1.bmp->Canvas->Ellipse(x-r,y-r,x+r,y+r);
    }
// find smeared stars and render join line
pic1.bmp->Canvas->Pen->Color=clBlue;
pic1.bmp->Canvas->Pen->Width=2;
for (i=0;i<xy.num;i+=2)
 for (j=i+2;j<xy.num;j+=2)
    {
    x=xy[i+0]-xy[j+0]; if (x<0) x=-x;
    y=xy[i+1]-xy[j+1]; if (y<0) y=-y;
    if ((x>=dx0)&&(x<=dx1))
     if ((y>=dy0)&&(y<=dy1))
        {
        pic1.bmp->Canvas->MoveTo(xy[i+0],xy[i+1]);
        pic1.bmp->Canvas->LineTo(xy[j+0],xy[j+1]);
        // here you can merge the stars i,j together instead.
        }
    }
pic1.bmp->Canvas->Pen->Width=1;
```

**I use my own picture class for images so some members are:**

`xs,ys` is size of image in pixels

`p[y][x].dd` is pixel at `(x,y)` position as 32 bit integer type

`clear(color)` clears entire image with `color`

`resize(xs,ys)` resizes image to new resolution

`bmp` is **VCL** encapsulated **GDI** Bitmap with `Canvas` access

`pf` holds actual pixel format of the image:

```
enum _pixel_format_enum
    {
    _pf_none=0, // undefined
    _pf_rgba,   // 32 bit RGBA
    _pf_s,      // 32 bit signed int
    _pf_u,      // 32 bit unsigned int
    _pf_ss,     // 2x16 bit signed int
    _pf_uu,     // 2x16 bit unsigned int
    _pixel_format_enum_end
    };
```

`color` and pixels are encoded like this:

```
union color
    {
    DWORD dd; WORD dw[2]; byte db[4];
    int i; short int ii[2];
    color(){}; color(color& a){ *this=a; }; ~color(){}; color* operator = (const color *a) { dd=a->dd; return this; }; /*color* operator = (const color &a) { ...copy... return this; };*/
    };
```

The bands are:

```
enum{
    _x=0,   // dw
    _y=1,

    _b=0,   // db
    _g=1,
    _r=2,
    _a=3,

    _v=0,   // db
    _s=1,
    _h=2,
    };
```

I also use mine dynamic list template so:

`List<double> xxx;` is the same as `double xxx[];`

`xxx.add(5);` adds `5` to end of the list

`xxx[7]` access array element (safe)

`xxx.dat[7]` access array element (unsafe but fast direct access)

`xxx.num` is the actual used size of the array

`xxx.reset()` clears the array and set `xxx.num=0`

`xxx.allocate(100)` preallocate space for `100` items

Here Preview of result:

[image: preview]

Red dots are detected stars from your plot image and blue lines shows which stars are linked/detected as smeared.